Encountered "Contract name 'IERC165' must be unique." error while doing "npx wagmi generate"
I have searched all my codes in src/ folder, and there is only one "IERC165".
Below is the search result of "grep 'IERC165' -r contracts/src":
contracts/src/lib/IERC721A.sol:    //                            IERC165
contracts/src/lib/ERC721A.sol:    //                            IERC165
contracts/src/lib/IERC2981.sol:import {IERC165} from "./IERC165.sol";
contracts/src/lib/IERC2981.sol:interface IERC2981 is IERC165 {
contracts/src/lib/ERC165.sol:import {IERC165} from "./IERC165.sol";
contracts/src/lib/ERC165.sol: * @dev Implementation of the {IERC165} interface.
contracts/src/lib/ERC165.sol:abstract contract ERC165 is IERC165 {
contracts/src/lib/ERC165.sol:     * @dev See {IERC165-supportsInterface}.
contracts/src/lib/ERC165.sol:        return interfaceId == type(IERC165).interfaceId;
contracts/src/lib/ERC2981.sol:import {IERC165} from "./IERC165.sol";
contracts/src/lib/ERC2981.sol:     * @dev See {IERC165-supportsInterface}.
contracts/src/lib/ERC2981.sol:    ) public view virtual override(IERC165, ERC165) returns (bool) {
contracts/src/lib/IERC165.sol:// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v5.0.0) (utils/introspection/IERC165.sol)
contracts/src/lib/IERC165.sol:interface IERC165 {

Any guru here having any ideas on how to solve this issue?

I have received answer somewhere else. wagmi.config.ts file needs to be modified.
